# Powershell XML - look for value, select other

Tags: xml, powershell

I have XML:

```
<tabela_kursow typ="A" uid="20a001">
 <numer_tabeli>001/A/NBP/2020</numer_tabeli>
 <data_publikacji>2020-01-02</data_publikacji>
 <pozycja>
  <nazwa_waluty>bat (Tajlandia)</nazwa_waluty>
  <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
  <kod_waluty>THB</kod_waluty>
  <kurs_sredni>0,1260</kurs_sredni>
 </pozycja>
 <pozycja>
  <nazwa_waluty>dolar amerykański</nazwa_waluty>
  <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
  <kod_waluty>USD</kod_waluty>
  <kurs_sredni>3,8000</kurs_sredni>
 </pozycja>
...
```

and I am trying to get kurs_sredni for particular kod_waluty.

What I have is:

```
$file=[xml](new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/$item.xml")
$tmp=$file.SelectSingleNode("//pozycja[@kod_waluty='USD']/../kurs_sredni").Value
$tmp2=$file.tabela_kursow.pozycja.kurs_sredni[7] -replace ",","."
```

$tmp is empty, while $tmp2 is correct but it is selected by index, not currency code.

How can I get kurs_sredni while searching for kod_waluty=USD?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$tmp=$xml.SelectNodes("//tabela_kursow/pozycja/kod_waluty[text()='USD']/../kurs_sredni").innertext -replace ",","."
```